# configure AP dd-wrt using telnet or ssh

Tags: router, access-point, dd-wrt

i want to **configure access point** using telnet , for example change SSID
i have tried the command:

```
iwlconfig ath0 ESSID newssid
```

and it work i can see the newssid when search for networks and also if i write:

```
iwlconfig
```

i can see that the interface ath0 have the new ssid, but if i go to GUI i still see the old  SSID , and if i reboot the AP , no changes will be saved, it will go back to old configurations
1-so how to save changes?
2-and i need more commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
nrvam commit
```

It should work.